How to send an AWS SES email in Lambda with aws-sdk v3 using the latest version of Node?
How can I validate a Google Recaptcha in AWS Lambda using NodeJS 20 and then send an email if successful with AWS SES? It is assumed the front-end facing form sends the Recaptcha response via the variable gRecapResp. A lot of the answers I found were using Node 16 or earlier which doesn't work the latest versions of Node. I would prefer not to use any packaged zips layers.

I could not find an up-to-date answer for Node 20 on AWS Lambda for an HTML Recaptcha validation so I designed one myself. You don’t need to add any packages or layers, but you will have to change some of the event variables and also add a Recaptcha secret. I hooked this up with API Gateway. It sends an email using SES if the recpatcha validation was successful (MailSent). gRecapResp is the user entered response on the front-end form. It gets sent via REST to the Lambda function via API Gateway. You will also want to change the two email addresses listed below. All of the event variables will need to be changed like event.name to suit your needs. If you have trouble along the way, use console.log or add a comment below.
'use strict';
import { HttpRequest } from "@aws-sdk/protocol-http";
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
import { NodeHttpHandler } from "@aws-sdk/node-http-handler";
export const reCaptchaSecret = "ADDSECRET";
const REGION = "us-east-1";
const sesClient = new SESClient({ region: REGION });
export { sesClient };

export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // Grab the following variable from the User facing form.
  console.log(event.gRecapResp);
  const apiUrl = new URL('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' + reCaptchaSecret + '&response=' + event.gRecapResp);
  const request = new HttpRequest({
    hostname: apiUrl.hostname.toString(),
    protocol: apiUrl.protocol,
    path: apiUrl.pathname +  apiUrl.search.toString(),
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "host": apiUrl.hostname.toString(),
    },
  });
  const client = new NodeHttpHandler();
  const { response } = await client.handle(new HttpRequest(request));
  console.log(response.statusCode + ' ' + response.body.statusMessage);
  var responseBody = '';
  await new Promise(() => {
    response.body.on('data', (chunk) => {
      responseBody += chunk;
    });
    response.body.on('end', () => {
      console.log('responseBody' + JSON.parse(responseBody).success);
      if (JSON.parse(responseBody).success) {
        const command = new SendEmailCommand({
          Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [
              'test@example.org'
            ]
          },
          Message: {
            Body: {
              Text: {
                Data: 'Name: ' + event.name + '\n\nEmail: ' + event.mail + '\n\nMessage: ' + event.message,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
              }
            },
            Subject: {
              Data: event.referrer + ' Website Referral: ' + event.name,
              Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
          },
          Source: 'test@example.com'
        });
        try {
          return sesClient.send(command);
        }
        catch (error) {
          callback('MailNotSent');
        }
        finally {
          callback(null, 'MailSent');
        }
      } else {
        callback('MailNotSent');
      }
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    callback('MailNotSent');
  });

};

